# Configure Gnome Evolution with Exchange 2007?

Tags: email, exchange-2007, evolution

I am running Ubuntu 9.04 and I would like to setup Gnome Evolution to read my mail/calendar from our Exchange 2007 server.

Has anyone successfully done this? If so, can you provide any tips or resources that helped you to configure this?

I have tried to use the Gnome Evolution Account Creation wizard, but that hasn't worked for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I know there is a new plugin for Evolution in Ubuntu Jaunty called **evolution-mapi** (install with "apt-get evolution-mapi" from the command line) which is supposed to add native MAPI support to Evolution.  I have had it working for mail, but didn't look at calendaring.

Might be worth looking at though.

Comment: From what I understand this requires the Samba 4 codebase to work. If you're not comfortable replacing your Samba with product that isn't even in beta yet, then it isn't for you.

Comment: I was able to use it with a vanilla install of 9.04 and it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Evolution back in Ubuntu 8 and you just point it at your Exchange 2007 Outlook Web Access URL and it just works fine for mail, contacts, calenders etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without using the evolution-mapi plugin, the only way I've done it is through IMAP. It doesn't provide a calendar, though which makes it of limited use in the office.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past using a **google calendar** as an intermediate.  Evolution hooks into the google calendar easily, and there was a plugin I found for evolution which allowed 2-way synching of my Exchange calendar with my google calendar (unfortunately I recently replaced my windows XP with windows 7, and didn't re-install this plugin - and forget what it was called)

However, **this does require that outlook be running** somewhere with this plugin to keep it in synch.

This solution **didn't work with extra (shared) calendars** either.  (well, it might if you could convince the "sharee" to set up the same plugin linked to a second google calendar).  I was only able to sync my primary calendar.

Answer (score 0):

@Brent,

May I know how you setup the MAPI? the Evolution always crashed when I input password on the authentication step.

Comment: Hmmm.  I seem to remember having to run it several times to get it to work.  But in the end, it worked.  (I think in my case I might have been typing something wrong)

Answer (score 0):

remove smb.conf from /etc/samba
seems not to crash after that